# What is the average lifespan of rear derailleurs?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear

What is the typical life cycle of mid-range rear derailleurs, assuming no accidents?

More precisely, what's the average mileage after which it's better to replace it rather than doing tuning all the time?

Comment: MTB or road? Recreational or compedative riding? Lotto winner or student? When you get tired of tuning it all the time or poor gear shifts is as good a time as any.....

Comment: Probably before its weak enough to go into your wheel. Though the useful life before sloppy shifting is determined a lot by maintenance (cleaning and oiling). Shifting is also a function of the shifter condition and cable condition, though.

Comment: If you have trouble "tuning" then I'd suspect that components elsewhere are the problem -- worn cables, bent derailleur hanger, etc.  And, of course, worn chain & cogs are a major reason for shifting problems

Answer (score 18):

Derailleurs will last almost indefinitely. The jockey wheels will wear out in time (tens of thousands of km) but the rest of the mechanism shouldn't see significant wear.

Comment: It could be that the spring will break at some point due to material fatigue, but that is also a relatively easy to replace part on most derailleurs. And the jockey wheels will go before that.

Comment: Yeah, the wheel bearings are *supposed* to be loose, and the pivots could easily last for decades without getting "sloppy", so physical damage is the only real factor in their life, beyond jockey wheel wear.

Comment: Re: derailleurs lasting almost indefinitely and pivots lasting decades: longevity  depends on make, model, miles per year and weather conditions. I raced for Shimano in 1980s, and my Dura-Ace EX derailleurs would barely make it through one racing season - pivot points got so loose shifting was unreliable. When we got the AX line, durability improved dramatically. I still use Shimano - Ultegra 8000. But after 4,000 miles the pivots are already loose enough that shifting is noticeably less crisp then when new. I'd say when to replace depends on your personal tolerance for sloppy shifting.

Answer (score 6):

My main road bike has campagnolo gran sport derailleurs.  That was mid range when I bought it back in 1980.  Probably over 100000 miles by now.  I have replaced cables and jockey wheels a few times but it still shifts great.

Comment: One thing to note that on a lot of newer derailleurs which arent high end, its usually nearly cheaper/easier to chuck the derailleur and put in a new one when the jockey wheels are gone rather than replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you shift when you ride and how much you knock it about. I am just about to replace my SRAM Apex 11 speed because the pivots are worn and the whole thing is bent out of shape. It's 18 months old and it looks like it might snap on my next ride!

Comment: What on earth are you doing to your bike?  I suppose it's possible you've put tens of thousands of km on your bike in that time, but it still seems extreme that it's in such bad shape in such a short time.  But the question was what should the average lifespan of a derailleur be?

Answer (score -1):

I got 23,000 miles out of my rear derailleur. The sprocket inside the derailleur broke loose and while it still worked it needed replacement. My bike is in the shop and I hope to get it back tomorrow. The first local bike shop just today told me it needed replacement and I took it to a second shop to confirm this. Make sure you find a shop you trust because I was told the derailleur needed replacement three years ago by a shop owner who tried to con me. It DID not need replacement three years ago. If you are unsure of whether to trust your local bike shop take the bike to another shop for a second opinion. I found many shops to be dishonest.  (12-12-2018)

Comment: So to focus your answer on the posed question of "when to replace rear derailleurs?" your answer is "when its broken" ?   Can you add info on whether you did any cleaning or maintenance?  Would the derailleur have been serviceable if the jockey wheels and shafts were swapped out?